# express middleware not firing

Tags: express, middleware

I am new to node.js and am running this file with `express-validator` as middleware to validate POST data in my requests.  But I am getting an error:

```
(function(){
  var express = require("express");
  var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

  var app = express();

  app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("inside my middleware")
    next();
  });

  app.configure(function(){
    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
  });

  app.post("/test", function(req, res){
    req.assert("email", "email is not valid").isEmail();
    res.send(200);
  })

  app.listen(app.get("port"), function(){
    console.log("API Server is available on port %s", app.get("port"));
  });

}());
```

It is telling me that the `/test` request on **POST** has no method assert which should be part of the `express-validator` middleware.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

According to it's [docs](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), you must also use express BodyParser middleware:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator([options])); // this line must be immediately after express.bodyParser()!
```

Comment: I've read that bodyParser() creates a lot of tmp files so it is better to use express.json() or urlencoded()

Comment: Did you try it with bodyParser to see if it fixes the problem?  The middleware function in express-validator makes use of both req.param and req.body so perhaps it's erroring without it

Comment: Yes `TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'assert'` is the error i get, also `req.body` is undefined.